# String Formatting Lost

Tags: vba, excel, string-formatting

I've written this code to create a list of email addresses from branch numbers. All the addresses are in the format:
`lp0000@xxx.co.uk`

The problem is some of the branch numbers are 3 digits so a zero is inserted in front of these e.g. 681 becomes 0681. I did this by using a custom number format `0000` but since the actual value of each is still `000` when the email addresses are created the starting zero is lost.

Can I write more code to copy the number format or do I need to write something to find all three digit numbers first and insert a 0 before them.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Pop_Emails()
    Dim brno As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = Sheets("1A")
    i = 2
    Do While i <> 191
        With wks
            brno = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            .Cells(i, 3) = "lp" & brno & "@xxxx.co.uk"
        End With
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print brno
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `(i, 1)` is `"0001"` with a custom format:

```
 brno = .Cells(i, 1).Value
```

will be `1`, to get the formatted value simply:

```
 brno = .Cells(i, 1).Text
```

Comment: @AlistairWeir: Please don't feel obliged to accept the fastest answer.  SO benefits from quality answers more than speedy ones.

Comment: This is a good answer, I agree and upvoted myself, but the program needs to be smarter than the end user making the Excel document. What if the custom format was accidently lost??  With padding or formatting in code, it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the number format within your VBA code:

```
.Cells(i, 3) = "lp" & Format(brno, "0000") & "@xxxx.co.uk"
```

Comment: Good answer, does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Excel is likely seeing it as a number, so it automatically converts it for you.  Gee thanks MS.

Anywho... not a big deal, just use `PadLeft()` to correct it.

```
brno = .Cells(i, 1).Value.PadLeft(4, "0")
```